# How to set up an Electron project based on AngularCLI, with debugging/live reload?

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli

I am trying to set up an AngularCLI project which can be run in the browser and via electron.

I've found some good tutorials for doing so, such as this article:

http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=806

However I cannot find or figure out a setup which allows for live reload and debugging in the electron project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `@angular/cli` :

- Create a folder `electron` next to `src` folder
- In this folder, create a file `electron.js`

Paste the following content in it :

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

// keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected
let win;

function createWindow() {
  // create the browser window
  win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.maximize();

  // and load the index.html of the app
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  //           THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE LOOKING FOR DEBUGGING
  // open the DevTools
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  // emitted when the window is closed
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // fereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element
    win = null;
  });
};

// yhis method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows
// some APIs can only be used after this event occurs
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// quit when all windows are closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // on macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // on macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

- In the same folder, create a file `generate-package-json.json`. This way we can automatically generate the package for our electron app like that :

file :

```
const fs = require('fs');

const package = `{ "name": "${ require('../package.json').name}", "version": "${ require('../package.json').version}", "main": "electron.js" }`;

fs.writeFile('./dist/package.json', package, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Then in your package.json :

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "build-electron": "npm run build -- -bh='./'; node ./electron/generate-package-json.js; cp ./electron/electron.js dist/",
    "electron": "npm run build-electron; electron dist/"
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, run `npm run electron`

Comment: Thanks for the response Maxime. Do I create the electron file "inside" the src folder?

Comment: You're welcome. No, in electron folder :  `electron/electron.js`

Comment: I tried your solution and it works but does not solve the problem. I was looking for something that will do live reload, I will edit my post to specify.